# How to read a badly formatted CSV file with multiple embedded data sets and non-printing characters

Tags: r, csv, read.table, read.csv

I need to open a CSV file with the following options in the figure below. I add the link to my files. You can try with the file "20140313_Helix2_FP140_SC45.csv"

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i5y8r8g7wymalw8/AABXsLkbpowxGObFpGHgv4m-a?dl=0

[image]

I have tried many options with read.table and read.csv but I need a dataframe with more than one column and data are separated.

Comment: I think you need to split your process in multiple steps. Your data are currently in a format that's very hard to read in in one go (as there is data and identifiers in the same position). So you either need to edit your file manually, or find a way to read it in as raw text and parse the lines after.

Comment: @Heroka you are right. But at least I would like to separate data in different columns. How can I do it?

Comment: depends on what form your final /edited data are. Looking at the raw text, it's definitely not a .csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like captured printer output. But it's not *too* messy:

```
# read it in as raw lines
lines <- readLines("20140313_Helix2_FP140_SC45.csv")
```

I'm assuming you want the "frequency point" data (it's the most prevalent) so we find the first one of those:

```
start <- which(grepl("^FREQUENCY POINTS:", lines))[1]
```

The rest of the file is "regular" *enough* to just look for lines beginning with a number (i.e. the `PNT` column) and read that in, giving it saner column names than the `read.table` default):

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(grep("^[0-9]+",lines[start:length(lines)], value=TRUE)),
                  col.names=c("PNT", "FREQ", "MAGNITUDE"))
```

And, here's the result:

```
head(dat)
##   PNT     FREQ MAGNITUDE
## 1   1 0.800000   -19.033
## 2   2 0.800125   -19.038
## 3   3 0.800250   -19.071
## 4   4 0.800375   -19.092
## 5   5 0.800500   -19.137
## 6   6 0.800625   -19.167

nrow(dat)
## [1] 1601
```

The # of rows matches (from what I can tell) the # of frequency point records.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr exactly what i was looking for